# Is there a way to read list & headers separately from CSV file without using any library in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, csv

So I've got a program made with my mentor, it's all about creating CSV file with list of objects who are premade.
But as I want to keep progressing, I want to make it more automatic.

The question is: **Can I make my program to read header of CSV file and append value to it while creating new list of objects without any non .NET library?**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            /*
            1. In new files create two classes: House (properties: Id - int, Surface - int, Name - string, IsFlat - bool, Description - string), Human (Id - int, BirthDate - DateTime, Height - byte)
            In Houses description use some commas and watch out for them as it is a common csv separator and may cause you some trouble.
            2. Create two lists with at least 5 elements each, one with Houses and one with Humans
            3. Create two csv files and append to them the right text (check in Excel if it works)
            4. Try to extract the data from the files - two new variables that will have exactly the same as the ones created manually in the second step
            */

            List<House> houses = new List<House>() {
                new House(1, 100, "Stanowski", true, "House has two separate floors, upstairs there is a bedroom and a toilet, downstairs family has living room, kitchen and small garderobe"),
                new House(2, 240, "Borek", false, "This house has also two floors, small garden outside and inside there is 3 bedrooms, huge living room and nice - modern kitchen."),
                new House(3, 140, "Pol", true, "This house has bald floors"),
                new House(4, 280, "Boniek", false, "This house is simply - TOP"),
                new House(5, 50, "Lewandowski", true, "This house has golden balls around the living room")
            };
            List<Human> humans = new List<Human>() {
                new Human(1, new DateTime(1980, 7, 21), 185),
                new Human(2, new DateTime(1986, 4, 7), 176),
                new Human(3, new DateTime(2000, 8, 21), 200),
                new Human(4, new DateTime(2004, 2, 20), 145),
                new Human(5, new DateTime(1995, 11, 11), 198)
            };
            var strFilePath = @"C:\Users\Szymon\source\repos\ProjektCSV\ProjektCSV\";
            var humanFileName = "humans.csv";
            var houseFileName = "houses.csv";
            // Take list of properties from an object. - ekspression 'nameof'

            var houseColumnNamesString = CsvTools.GetClassPropertiesString<House>();

            var humanColumnNamesString = CsvTools.GetClassPropertiesString<Human>();

            
            var humanValues = new StringBuilder("");
            foreach (var human in humans)
            {
                humanValues.Append($"{human.Id};{human.BirthDay};{human.Height};\n");
            }

            
            using (StreamWriter fileHuman = new StreamWriter(strFilePath + humanFileName, false))
            {
                fileHuman.WriteLine(humanColumnNamesString);
                fileHuman.WriteLine(humanValues);
            }
            // Separate to different methods/classes 
            
            
            var readCSV = CsvTools.ReadCsv(strFilePath + houseFileName);
            Console.WriteLine(readCSV);
            
            
            //TODO
            // Make automatic reading of properties and it's values, like instead of house.ID in line 72
            using (var reader = new StringReader(manyLines))
            {
                string? item;
                do {
                    item = reader.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                    } while(item != null);
            }
            var houseValues = new StringBuilder("");
            foreach (var house in houses)
            {
                houseValues.Append($"{house.Id};{house.Name};{house.Surface};{house.IsFlat};{house.Description};\n");
            }
            using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(strFilePath+houseFileName, false)) // true = add | false = overwrite
            { 
                file.WriteLine(houseColumnNamesString);
                file.WriteLine(houseValues);
            }
        }
```

**Okay, so is that what I needed?**

```
using(StreamReader file = new StreamReader(strFilePath + houseFileName))
            {
                string line;
                string headers = line.Take(1);
                while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null )
                {
                    var content = new List<House>(line);
                }    
            }
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to?

Comment: Just for the challenge

Comment: So what is your problem? How to do what? How to map class properties or attributes to header names?

Comment: The problem is: Can I make my program to read header of CSV file and append value to it while creating new list of objects. Like I have created list 'House' manually. But I want my code to create new list while reading lines from CSV file and do it without any extra non-microsoft library - like CSVHelper.

Comment: The file just has lines; right? So the first line is the header. Why wouldn't you be able to read the first line from the file and get the header and then do whatever you want to the file after?

Comment: Yeah but how do I separate first line? And make exact list from the columns i want? THey also have strict type.
Do I just do this:
`
string line;
using(StreamReader)
if(line == 1){
var newList = List<T>(string);
}
// rest of the code
foreach(string s in reader) {
   var newList = new List{};
   newList.Append(string);
}
`
Or something like that? @ChiefTwoPencils

Comment: Let's imagine you read your file as `List<string> lines`, so `string headers = lines.Take(1)` `List<string> content = lines.Skip(1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use C# Reflection to traverse through the collection and build your data. Below is the snippet which shows how to achieve this. It gives you the approach but I have not build exactly the way you want the string to be:

```
var houses = new List<House>
                {
                    new House{Id = 1, Name = "Boulevard", Surface = "Plain"},
                    new House{Id = 2, Name = "Geneva", Surface = "Mat"},
                    new House{Id = 3, Name = "Lyncroft", Surface = "Carpet"}
                };

                var properties = Type.GetType("GenericRewriteDateIssueTest.House").GetProperties();
                var houseValues = new StringBuilder("");

                foreach (var house in houses)
                {
                    foreach (var prop in properties)
                    {
                        houseValues.Append($"{prop.GetValue(house)};");
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Yeah so that's similar to my code in working way, but I want to take properties from CSV file and create completely new list, without using in your situation `prop.GetValue(house)` - this has to be done automatically by reading the lines

Comment: If i understand your problem correct, why not read the values from the header and build a list of anonymous types. Or, use something like this to set the value
house.GetType().GetProperty("<csv hearder name>").SetValue(house, <csv column value>);